# Not able to get Nginx to show anything other than "welcome to nginx"

Tags: debian, webserver, nginx

I am trying to set up an nginx install on a Amazon Lightsail VPS running Debian (not the Nginx Bitnami package). I'm a bit of a newbie at this.  I'm totally puzzled by what is happening.

#### Output of `ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 27 16:39 static -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/static
```

#### Contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/static`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  'DOMAIN NAME' www.'DOMAIN NAME' www1.'DOMAIN NAME' 'IP ADDRESS OF SERVER'

    root /var/www/static
    index index.html;

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

In the above, `DOMAIN_NAME` and `IP ADDRESS` are placeholders for the real text.

Output of `nginx -T` shows the contents of `static` displayed after the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  There are no `server-name` lines in this output except what's in `static`.

`/var/log/nginx/access.log` shows accesses when I enter the main domain name, but not the subdomain names.  In any case, whether I enter the subdomain or just the main domain, I am shown the welcome page.

What's even more mystifying is that the welcome page seems to be at `/var/www/html/index.html`. So I modified that file too as a test. But the modified version wasn't displayed either.

I'm at my wit's end.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try looking within `/var/www/static` instead of `/var/www/html`

Comment: Is each statement terminated with a `;`? Your example shows some missing `;`s.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not displaying the index.html in `/var/www/static` - that's the problem at present.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'll check this!

Comment: @RichardSmith you were right, that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @RichardSmith on the question pointed me to the right answer.

I'd used code from other websites to construct my server block file (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/static`). But some of that code was wrong - it did not terminate every line with a `;`.

Once I added that to the file, like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  'DOMAIN NAME' www.'DOMAIN NAME' www1.'DOMAIN NAME' 'IP ADDRESS OF SERVER';

    root /var/www/static;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly!

**NB:** Wish `nginx -t` would have given me a warning about this though...